# What is causing multiple definition error when building with ASan?

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer

So I am trying to identify some memory corruption issues in a large codebase. To begin with, I first built the codebase as it is with whatever existing makefile configuration was set up already. It worked fine and the binaries were generated. Now I added `-g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-common` in compile flags and `-fsanitize=address` (also tried with -lasan if that makes any difference) in link flags to compile the codebase with ASan. But now I am getting multiple declaration errors at link time. I am clueless at this point. What could be the reason for this? If there were multiple definitions, then shouldn't the same error pop up when building without ASan flags too? I couldn't even find anything related to this in the ASan docs.

I cannot share the exact error trace, but it pretty much looks like this:

```
path/to/file/hdr.h:132: multiple definition of `myDataTable_type'
path/to/file/hdr.h:132: first defined here
path/to/obj/file/obj.o: multiple definition of `__odr_asan.myDataTable_type'
```

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)

Comment: _"If there were multiple definitions, then shouldn't the same error pop up when building without ASan flags too?"_ Did you also build with `-fno-common` before? And on that note: what is `myDataTable_type`? A global variable? If so, declare it in the header file but move its definition to a .c file.

Comment: No -fno-common wasn't there earlier. Removing it did the job. It is a legacy codebase actually. Thank you :)

Comment: @Michael yes myDataTable_type is a global variable 'defined' in the hdr file. I am not really supposed to make any changes in the src code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have something like

```
XXX myDataTable_type;
```

in one of the headers. When this header is included into multiple source files you'll get multiple definitions error under `-fno-common`.

To resolve this you could either remove `-fno-common` from `CFLAGS` but then Asan will not be able to detect buffer overflows in some static arrays. Better yet, just get rid of multiple definitions by changing declaration in header to

```
extern XXX myDataTable_type;
```

and adding

```
XXX myDataTable_type;
```

to one of the source files (to guarantee single definition).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I removed -fno-common and built the codebase but ASan throws a segmentation fault as soon as it runs now.

Comment: @HumaidKidwai Hm, this definitely shouldn't happen. Maybe create a new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192914/why-does-asan-throw-a-segmentation-fault-here