# Why does ASan throw a segmentation fault here?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, address-sanitizer

So this is a follow up to my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189421/what-is-causing-multiple-definition-error-when-building-with-asan/74190202?noredirect=1#comment130992158_74190202)

I am trying to build a legacy codebase with Address Sanitizer. As soon as I run the binary, I get a Segmentation Fault.

```
==2940167==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x000002aa79a0 at pc 0x000000d6aaf4 bp 0x7fffe7244140 sp 0x7fffe7244130
READ of size 4 at 0x000002aa79a0 thread T3

Thread 1 "block_hk.xcg." received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Here is the trace with gdb:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6f0dc26 in __sanitizer::internal_strlen(char const*) () from /lib64/libasan.so.5
#1  0x00007ffff6e57208 in printf_common(void*, char const*, __va_list_tag*) () from /lib64/libasan.so.5
#2  0x00007ffff6e59566 in vsnprintf () from /lib64/libasan.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff540ed5c in ?? () from /lib64/libdus.so
#4  0x00007ffff540f017 in ?? () from /lib64/libdus.so
#5  0x00007ffff540f860 in ?? () from /lib64/libdus.so
#6  0x00007ffff541a443 in logPrint () from /lib64/libdus.so
#7  0x00007ffff4761734 in mcsCreateSem () from /lib64/libcwl.so
#8  0x00007ffff4764b14 in mcsInitialize () from /lib64/libcwl.so
#9  0x00007ffff47678fc in cwlAppRunCPP () from /lib64/libcwl.so
#10 0x000000000112d719 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffe7478) at ./src/main.c:755
```

Comment: The logPrint inside mcsCreateSem, check the format and the parameters. Forgetting to give an argument to %s can go unnoticed and cause all kinds of issues.

Comment: @Eben As per the stack trace, it seemed as if a statement in logPrint() caused the segmentation fault. But actually the segmentation fault was caused by the vnsprintf function call with a NULL format string. ASan (w/ gcc 8.4.1) can not handle a NULL format string in vnsprintf and causes the segmentation fault error. When built without ASan, there is no crash observed.

Comment: AFAIK a null format string is undefined behavior, so ASan is right to consider it an error.  If your program was written for a platform where `vnsprintf(NULL, ...)` was well defined, you may have to wrap it.